# Проблема с рекурсией

Tags: php, алгоритм, рекурсия

Возможно я просто не силен в данной сфере, но задача состоит в том, что я присылаю на сервер название файлов, оно уже их ищет и записывает данные в БД.

```
$server = "server";
$search_file = $_POST['search_file'];

echo "вы прислали на сайт следующие данные:<br>";
foreach ($search_file as $item) {
    echo $item . "<br>";
    $str = "";
    $aqa = search_file($server, $item, $str);
    echo $aqa;
}

function search_file($path, $fileName,$sq)
{
    $dir = opendir($path);
    while ($d = readdir($dir)) {
        if ($d == '.' || $d == '..') continue;
        if (is_file($path . '/' . $d)) {
            if ($d == $fileName) {
                $sq .= $path . '/' . $d ;
                // echo $path . '/' . $d . "<br>";
            }
        } else if (is_dir($path . '/' . $d)) {
            search_file($path . '/' . $d, $fileName,$sq);
        }
    }
    return $sq;
}
```

Почему то моя переменная обновляется, хотя объявляю я ее за пределами первого вызова. как решить данную проблему?

Answer (score 0):

```
while ($d = readdir($dir)) {
```

замените на:

```
while (false !== ($d = readdir($dir))) {
```